# Why does env.readTextFile(...).first(10).print in Flink read all data?

Tags: apache-flink

When I only want to take the first N records in Apache Spark I use:

```scala
sc.textFile(path_to_files).take(10)
```

Which will return quickly and give me the first 10 lines of text.
When I do something similar in Apache Flink:

```scala
env.readTextFile(path_to_files).first(10).print()
```

It will read all files completely before returning the results. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink uses a pipelined (stream based) execution model. Thus, when starting the program, the source just starts to consume data, not knowing about downstream operators. Therefore, all data gets read and `first(10)` only return 10 records.

Due to the pipelined execution model, it is difficult to apply an optimization to stop the source early. Imagine, that there might be filters, aggregates etc in between, so the source cannot know how many data it must read in order to end up with 10 final result records.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.